# How to export video frame to NSData from CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I want to upload video to server using `AVFoundation` to capture video.Core Media represents video data using `CMSampleBuffer` but how to get the video data so i can send it to server?There is an example about converting `CMSampleBuffer` to a `UIImage` Object but i can't find an example about converting `CMSampleBuffer` to a `NSData` Object.

Answer (score -1):

You can render the image and export the resulting image data using a `CIContext` instance:

```
guard let buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self) else { return nil }

let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)
let context = CIContext()
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let data = context.jpegRepresentation(of: ciImage, colorSpace: colorSpace, options:[:])
```

See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1642214-jpegrepresentation) for further information, there are other options like: `tiffRepresentation(of:format:colorSpace:options:)`, `pngRepresentation(of:format:colorSpace:options:)`, etc.